# auto fill text field based on combo selection in laravel jquery javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, laravel

I met difficulties in the autofill text field based on combo selection using Laravel and jQuery or JavaScript. I've searched for days with nothing.

**ContractController.php**

```
 public function create()
 {
    $order = Order::all();
    return view('contract.create', compact('order'));
}
```

**create.blade.php**

```
<select name="cde_order" id="cde_order" class="form-control" required>
    <option disabled selected> -- PICK -- </option>
    @foreach($order as $order)
    <option value="{{ $order->cde_order }}" data-price="{{ $order->addr_customer }}">{{ $order->nme_customer }}</option>
    @endforeach
</select>

<input type="text" name="addr_contract" id="addr_contract" class="form-control">
```

**web.php**

```
Route::resource('contract','ContractController');
```

here is my order model :

**Model order**

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Order extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'tbl_order';
    protected $primaryKey = 'cde_order';

    protected $fillable = [
        'nme_customer', 'add_customer', 'phone_customer', 'msg_order'
    ];

    public function contract()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Contract');
    }
}
```

and this is for the contract model:
**Model Contract**

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;


class Contract extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'tbl_contract';
    protected $primaryKey = 'cde_contract';

    protected $fillable = [
        'cde_order', 'add_customer'
    ];


    public function order()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Order');
    }
}
```

here is the migration file for order table
**Order Migration**

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

class CreateTableOrder extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('tbl_order', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('cde_pesan');
            $table->string('nme_customer');
            $table->string('add_customer');
            $table->string('phone_customer');
            $table->integer('msg_order');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('tbl_order');
    }
}
```

and this is the migration file for contract tabel
**Contract Migration**

```
<?php

  use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;
  use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
  use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

class CreateTableContract extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('tbl_contract', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('cde_contract');
            $table->integer('cde_order')->unsigned();

            $table->string('add_contract');
            $table->string('phone_customer');
            $table->timestamps();

            $table->foreign('cde_order')->references('cde_order')->on('tbl_order')
                ->onDelete('cascade');
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('tbl_contract');
    }
}
```

Comment: what you want bind in text box  `data-price` ? and what is `$order->addr_customer` object or filed?

Comment: it is a field, if user choose cust name as values in combo box, the text field fill with the address of the customer. how to do it either from model, route, controller, view in laravel using either js or jquery and or ajax

Comment: put your models with fields and relationship

Comment: i've done that in the beginning working this project put the field and relationship in models.

Comment: i mean please put model and relationship in this question so can see you code and give you solution

Comment: address of customer is in order table field named with add_customer...? then i updated my answer try it

Comment: yes it is in the order table field name add_customer. but still can not work. the text field stood empty not fill by the select combo.

Answer (score 0):

You can work with `change()` event and Set address of as data- attribute and get on change() event

```php
<select name="cde_order" id="cde_order" class="form-control" required>
    <option disabled selected> -- PICK -- </option>
    @foreach($order as $order)
        <option value="{{ $order->cde_order }}" data-address="{{ $order->add_customer }}">{{ $order->nme_customer }}</option>
    @endforeach
</select>
```

```
<script>
$('#cde_order').change(function(){
    var addr = $(this).find('option:selected').data('address');
    $('#addr_contract').val(addr);
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<select data-route="{{route('contract.show')}}" name="cde_order" id="cde_order" class="form-control" required>
    <option disabled selected> -- PICK -- </option>
    @foreach($order as $order)
    <option value="{{ $order->cde_order }}" data-price="{{ $order->addr_customer }}">{{ $order->nme_customer }}</option>
    @endforeach
</select>
```

in ajax

```
$('#cde_order').change(function(e){
e.preventDefault();

   $.ajaxSetup({
             headers: {
                 'X-CSRF-TOKEN': token
             }
         });
         //e.preventDefault();
         var route  = $(this).attr('data-route');  
         var id     = $(this).val();        
         $.ajax({
             type:'post',
             url :route,
             dateType:'json',
             data:{id:id},
             success: function (data){
                 if (data.status==true){
                       $('#addr_contract').text(data.objctData.name) 
//objctData is the object you want take property from it
                     });
                 }else{

                 }
             },error:function(){
                 alert('error,try again');
             }
         });

})
```

in your controller

```
public function show(Request $request){
$id =$request->id;
// here get data from your model and return
return response()->json(['objctData'=>$objctData])
}
```